# Необходимо сделать так, чтобы WordPress обращался к необходимой таблице в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

У меня есть два сайта, они размещены на одном хостинге и у них одна и та же БД, оба сайта на WordPress и у обоих сайтов разные префиксы у таблиц, у одной "wp_", а другого - "wpk1_". Мне надо сделать так, чтобы зарегистрировавшись на одном сайте, можно было использовать тот же самый логин и пароль на другом сайте. На первом сайте используется таблица для пользователей под названием "wp_users", а на другой сайте эта таблица называется "wpk1_users".

Я нашел тут два варианта решения этой проблемы:

1) Первый заключается в том, чтобы связать эти таблицы, то есть при добавлении пользователя в одну таблицу, данные об этом пользователе добавлялись бы автоматические в другую таблицу. Но я не знаю, как это сделать.

2) Второй вариант заключается в том, чтобы где-то в настройках WordPress изменить что-то так, чтобы оба сайта обращались к одной и той же таблице пользователей.

Если вы сталкивались с данной проблемой или знаете как ее решить, буду очень благодарен за любую информацию!

P.S: Структура у обеих таблиц одинаковая.

Comment: Используйте WordPress Multisite https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/ustanovka-multisite-mu

Answer (score 6):

Вы могли бы использовать 1-ну таблицу users и user meta, но у разных сайтов разные настройки различных солей и ключей( AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SALT, LOGGED_IN_SALT ... ). Так что у вас имея одинаковый зашифрованный пароль в базе вы не сможете подключится с другого сайта с другим наборов этих солей и ключей.

Можете добавить костыль и добавлять пользователя на другой сайт через https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_user/, но тут будет проблема со сменой паролей.

Лучший вариант для таких целей использовать мультисайт и не придумывать велосипед: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/ustanovka-multisite-mu